# I was trying to automate website every time i press a certain point it doesn't click

Tags: python, html, xpath, automation, discord

here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import urllib.request
from pydub import AudioSegment
import speech_recognition as sr
import time




driver = Chrome()
token = "token"
driver.get("https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=282859044593598464&scope=identify+guilds+email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://probot.io/api/auth")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script('window.t = "' + token + '";window.localStorage = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage;window.setInterval(() => window.localStorage.token = `"${window.t}"`); window.location.reload();')
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[2]").click()
time.sleep(50)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(text(),'Claim your daily reward')])[1]").click()
time.sleep(60)
driver.close()
```

I tried to use the CSS selector but it still gives me the same

```
errorselenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[contains(text(),'Claim your daily reward')])[1]"}
```